# What is the diffusivity of colloidal Formazine in water?

Tags: optics, statistical-mechanics, physical-chemistry, specific-reference, polymers

I have synthesized Foramzine in an aqueous solution (turbidity = 4000 NTU), and will be further diluting it. I would like to know the diffusion coefficient (diffusivity/mass diffusivity) of colloidal Formazine in water. Is there existing literature where I could find this information?